# Error: 'laravelcollective/html' has been abandoned when installing packages for roles and permissions

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm working on setting up roles and permissions in my Laravel project and encountered an error with my composer.json file. When I tried to install packages, specifically `"laravelcollective/html"`, I received the following error message: **'laravelcollective/html' has been abandoned.**

I've already attempted running `php artisan optimize:clear` and `php artisan config:clear` as suggested in other solutions, but the issue persists.

How can I resolve this error and successfully install the necessary packages for implementing roles and permissions in Laravel? Any guidance or alternative packages would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Clearing your application cache won't remove an abandoned package. You coud try to reimplement its functionality with `spatie/laravel-html`

Comment: The package being abandoned is not an error, its just for your information. You can still use it if you wish but don't expect any existing bugs  or vulnerabilities to be fixed or any new features to be added.